# Google Script - Find and Replace using "Search Within Formulas"

Tags: replace, google-apps-script

I have a google sheet that receives a list of phone numbers from an outside source. Phone numbers arrive in one of two formats:

1. Numbers that appear as 12345678901 are seen without error.
2. Numbers that appear as 1(234)567-8901 result in `#ERROR!`.

It seems that google sheets is reading the second set of numbers as a formula. When I click into an error cell, the phone number is preceded with "=+", as in "=+1(234)567-8901". I can fix this manually for the entire document by using Find and Replace with "Search within Formulas" checked.

Find: "=+"
Replace: " "

[image: Find/Replace "Search Within Formulas"]

Is there any way to automate this within google apps scripts? I would like to run this function `onEdit()` so that `#ERROR!` phone numbers are fixed in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the ()- characters using a spreadsheet formula, let's say the number was in cell A1, then in another cell you can put:

```
=CONCATENATE(SPLIT(A1, "()-" ))
```

which will remove the ()- characters.

If you would like to do this with a script then you can use replace to remove the ()-

```
.replace(/[()-]/gi, "")
```

apply above your number column range to properly format number.

**EDIT**

This should work, change "A1:A" to your column

```
function onEdit(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var data = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  for (var i=0;i< formulas.length;i++) {
    if(typeof formulas[i] !== "undefined" && formulas[i] != ""){
      formulas[i][0] = formulas[i][0].replace(/[=()+-]/gi, "");
      data[i][0] = formulas[i][0].toString();
    }
  }
 range.setValues(data).setNumberFormat("0");
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the delayed post, I haven't had a lot of time to work on this.
I'm struggling greatly with the syntax here. I'm trying to apply your `.replace(/[()-]/gi, "")` to a single column so that it replaces all `#ERROR!` phone numbers in column D.

Comment: Also, I have tried standard find and replace and it will not alter any data within the `#ERROR!` cell. The `#ERROR!` cells are only impacted when "search within formulas" is selected. I don't know if it's possible to do this within a script.

Comment: yes you are correct.  Ok so how are you importing numbers?  Maybe there is a way to format before sending the numbers to the spreadsheet.

Comment: my edit in my answer should be what you are looking for.

Comment: bloody brilliant. alright, I have to ask now - is there a way to re-format the numbers after they are fixed (preferrably in 1(123) 456-7890 format)

Note that the numbers may be varying lengths due to different country codes or lack of country code at all.

Comment: yes, I added it at the end: range.setValues(data).setNumberFormat("0");  You can find number formats here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: okay, last question. after the script runs, phone numbers appear with a space after the area code (Ex: 1222 3334444) which prevents the custom number format in the script from working on these cells. how can i remove that space before the custom number format is applied?

Comment: ^ it appears i have solved this by literally adding a space in the `.replace` string. updated string here: `replace(/[=() +-]/gi, "")`. Thanks for your help utphx!